# Using Jquery how do I get a div element to center vertically and horizontally on page load?

Tags: jquery, positioning

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ97A/3/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="greeter" class="welcomer">
    <h1>This should be centered</h1>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).resize(function(){

    $('.welcomer').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.welcomer').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.welcomer').outerHeight())/2
    });

});

// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();

});​
```

​

There seems to be a bug in how this works.  Some times it will center and other times it will only center vertically or horizontally.  I am new to javascript and jquery, is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lookie here: http://jsfiddle.net/zQ97A/13/

Basically you need to have width on your container and you also need the following code:

```
"top": ((($(window).height() - $('.welcomer').outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px"),
"left": ((($(window).width() - $('.welcomer').outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px")
```

Comment: what do the scrollTop() and scrollLeft() functions do?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/


Description: Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements.


That way it will center it on the page when you invoke that code, even if you have scrolled to something. If you don't want that behavior, you can still do $(window).width() and height() instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

To my taste it's better to have a class defined en a css, and then set that class to a div into your dom with jquery.

```
#custom.css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -(your_div_height/2)px;
  margin-left: -(your_div_weight/2)px;
}

#custom.js
$(#greeter).addClass("center")
```

I thing this is more faster becouse the **css** files load before the **js** files

Answer (score 0):

If you define a width for your *.welcomer* DIV, your code will work perfectly!